# Multi-day count total with restart after Y days

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr, databricks

I want to create a `total_dose` variable that continues to add up the values in the `dosage` variable. Once the `dosage` is 7 days old, it is subtracted from the `total_dose` variable.

This process continues on a rolling basis. I want code so that the total_dose count starts again when the `pid` or `medname` changes.

Dummy dataset:

```
  pid    medname    date              route     
1  1     drugA    2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     
2  1     drugA    2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     
3  1     drugA    2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     
4  2     drugB    2023-04-27 22:00:00 patch     
5  2     drugB    2023-04-30 13:15:00 patch     
6  2     drugB    2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     
7  2     drugA    2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch
```

Desired output

```
  pid    medname    date              route     dosage   total_dose
1  1     drugA    2023-04-15 17:30:00 patch     30       30
2  1     drugA    2023-04-16 11:45:00 patch     30       60
3  1     drugA    2023-04-17 10:30:00 patch     30       90
4  2     drugB    2023-04-27 22:00:00 patch     30       30
5  2     drugB    2023-04-30 13:15:00 patch     30       60
6  2     drugB    2023-05-10 13:15:00 patch     30       30
7  2     drugA    2023-05-11 06:30:00 patch     30       30
```

The code that has been attempted:

```
df2 <- transform(df1, total_dosage = ave(dosage, list(pid, medname,
                      cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1]))) > 604800)), 
                 FUN = cumsum))
```

Using with a `group_by` function:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(pid, medname) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) 

df3 <- transform(df2,
        total_dose = ave(dose, cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1]))) > 604800), 
                 FUN=cumsum))
```

Further attempt when using `group_by`:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(pid, medname) %>% 
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) 

df3 <- transform(df2, 
            time_since_first_dose = cumsum(c(0, diff(as.numeric(date - date[1])))), 
            group_change = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(pid) != 0 | diff(medname) != 0)), 
            total_dose = ave(dosage, group_change, time_since_first_dose, FUN=cumsum))
```